# Moodle Rest Console API For grades

Tags: android, ios, web-services, moodle

I'm developing an app Moodle public which will be a free app, and I have found few API's like token, login, user profile, participant list many more, but now for further API I searched on Moodle core API but the all code is in PHP and don't know PHP. I don't know what parameters required with grade or assignment functions. How use Core API functions.

I required API (URLs) so that I can test those API in rest console. Is there any document or list API URLs in which clearly mentioned what parameters need to be pass and how use Core API functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login as an admin user in Moodle and navigate below path to get API documentation of web services in moodle.

Administration Settings block > Plugins > Web services > API documentation.